# SearchCursor not reading the last row

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-3, count

Let's say I have a layer made up of pre-selected features from another layer:

```
selects = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (S_FIRM_Pan, "NEW_SELECTION", "DFIRM_ID = '{}'".format(fipC))
```

If I get a count of the number of these selected features, I get says, 199.

```
getCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(selects)
print(str(getCount))
>>>199
```

Checking in arcMap, I can see that this is the correct number. I then try to use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` to get all of the values for a certain field for `selects`:

```
raw_firm_pan = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selects, "FIRM_PAN")]
```

If I use `print(len(raw_firm_pan))` it only gives me 198 items. When I print it out and compare it to the actual rows for `selects` in arcMap, it appears that the last row is being cut off! How can I fix this?

Comment: `selects` is a result object, not a layer which you can pass to the SearchCursor. Try: `raw_firm_pan = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(S_FIRM_Pan, "FIRM_PAN")` then `len(raw_firm_pan)` Or try passing the layer to getCount: `arcpy.GetCount_management(S_FIRM_Pan)`

Comment: The problem with this approach is I don't want to search all of the layer `S_FIRM_Pan`, only the items "selected" by attribute; hence my  `selects`. And despite it being a results object, I am able to get all of the items from `selects` into list `raw_firm_pan`. All of them except the last row. It is the missing values from the last row that is the mystery.

Comment: After you use select by attribute S_FIRM_Pan will only consist of the selected features. The "unselected" S_FIRM_Pan will have been replaced

Comment: If you want to keep S_FIRM_Pan use MakeFeatureLayer on it and pass the sql statement to this. You will then get a new layer with only the matching records and not mess up your original layer.

Comment: arrays start at 0..... not sure if this applies to your count issue.

Comment: Yeah, but I am just getting the length of a list, which just counts the actual length, not the index. Also, I physically checked the last item in the list and it showed as the next to last item in the selected features (using the same select by attribute query that I ran in my script).

Comment: Very odd, what is environment extent setting?

Comment: I didn't really set any, so just default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this coding pattern instead:

```
raw_firm_pan = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(S_FIRM_Pan, "FIRM_PAN", "DFIRM_ID = '{}'".format(fipC))]
```

I have applied the selection using a `where_clause` when creating the cursor object instead of using the `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()` function.  I rarely use the latter because many ArcPy functions allow you to use a `where_clause`.